# Clothes moving weirdly after rigging

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging

I'm trying to rig this character but the clothes are having this weird 'behavior'

PS: the clothes is joined to the body

This is what keeps happening to the clothes:
https://gyazo.com/e2de07ff431b7653148a7360ce5e2d0e

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please use the image adding system so we can see the image without following the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution to your problem is to manually assign and remove vertices from the weight groups. having very little geometry as you do, it should be fairly simple to tweak the weights based on the geometry.
This can be accessed through the vertex group panel (upside-down triangle)
Based on your description I cannot tell if you have tried this yet or not.